# regex start with 1 of 3 values and is 9 digits

Tags: regex

I need a regex that makes sure a values starts with either:

60, 07, or 80

and is 9 digits long

Please can someone help with this.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^(?:60|07|80)\d{7}$` should suit your needs.

Comment: Your first one is fine; your second allows values such as 00, etc.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Oh yes, you're right, I removed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
/(07|60|80)[\d]{7}/
```

should do it.