# How do I combine 3 commands into 1 for regex and awk + want to regex on 3 possibilities e.g. 9,10,11

Tags: regex, awk

How do I combine these 3 commands

```
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] awk -F, '$2=="AMWPF" && $4=="RRH[0_11_0]/SFP[0]" {print $0}' data/20230706/IM_HW_20230706.csv 
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_11_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211300012948  ,2021-03-26,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[11]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] awk -F, '$2=="AMWPF" && $4=="RRH[0_10_0]/SFP[0]" {print $0}' data/20230706/IM_HW_20230706.csv 
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_10_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211300012955  ,2021-03-26,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[10]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] 
[senz_sims_db:/home/sims] awk -F, '$2=="AMWPF" && $4=="RRH[0_9_0]/SFP[0]" {print $0}' data/20230706/IM_HW_20230706.csv 
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_9_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211200053451  ,2021-03-19,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[9]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
```

into 1 regex command e.g. something like

xxxx`RRH[0_[9][10][11]_0]/SFP[0]`xxx

```
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_11_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211300012948  ,2021-03-26,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[11]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_10_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211300012955  ,2021-03-26,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[10]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_9_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211200053451  ,2021-03-19,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[9]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
```

### EDIT - based on answer below, 1st one does not work, 2nd does

```
>awk -F, '$2=="AMWPF" && $4~"^RRH\[0_(9|10|11)_0]/SFP\[0]$" {print $0}' data/20230706/IM_HW_20230706.csv 
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
>awk -F, '$2=="AMWPF" && $4 ~ /^RRH\[0_(9|10|11)_0]\/SFP\[0]$/  {print $0}' data/20230706/IM_HW_20230706.csv 
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_9_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211200053451  ,2021-03-19,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[9]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_10_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211300012955  ,2021-03-26,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[10]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
eNB_618378,AMWPF,RRHSFP,RRH[0_11_0]/SFP[0],SFP,N/A,RTXM228-601     ,N/A,WTD             ,HN211300012948  ,2021-03-26,N/A,N/A,N/A,ENB[618378]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]/PORT[11]/CASC[0]/CPRI_PORT[0],N/A,-,wavelength=TX:1310(nm)/RX:-(nm)
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728810/regex-start-with-1-of-3-values-and-is-9-digits) is a possible duplicate but I believe my question is different as it is regx in awk

Comment: Something like `$4 ~ /RRH\[(0_(9|10|11)_0)\]\/SFP\[0\]/`?

Comment: @Reilas that's for a static regexp, a dynamic regecp is delimited by `"`s, see the reference in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these will work:

```
$4 ~ /^RRH\[0_(9|10|11)_0]\/SFP\[0]$/

$4 ~ "^RRH\\[0_(9|10|11)_0]/SFP\\[0]$"

$4 ~ "^RRH[[]0_(9|10|11)_0]/SFP[[]0]$"
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for the difference between the 2 delimiters, `/` vs `"`.

You could also use `(9|1[01])` instead of `(9|10|11)` if you prefer.

Comment: tks - 1st one does not work, 2nd does, will see if I can fix

Comment: @HattrickNZ regarding the regexp that didn't work, I modified it in my answer - backslashes have to be doubled in dynamic regexps as explained in the article I linked. Going forward, always provide sample input in your questions, not just expected output, so we have something to copy/paste to test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the capture group, to provide the possible matches.

As a note, the `[` and `]` characters are part of the syntax, so instead of escaping the values, I am using a `.`, which is the wildcard character.

```
RRH.0_(11|10|9)_0..SFP.0.
```

Although, you could also use,

```
RRH\[0_(11|10|9)_0\]\/SFP\[0\]
```

Here is the *AWK* documentation, outlining regular expression use.
*[Regexp (The GNU Awk User’s Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html)*.

Comment: Those would match various contents of $4 that the OP does not want to match due to wildcards and lack of anchors.

Comment: @EdMorton, what would it additionally match?

Comment: The first one would match `RRH90_11_054SFPX0Y` and they'd both match the middle of `ABCRRH0_11_0]/SFP[0]DEF`.

Comment: @EdMorton, I don't see an RRH90.  What is the data? I don't recognize it.

Comment: The OP didn't show us sample input, just expected output, so we have to imagine what the input might contain that could look like the strings the OP wants to match but are not the strings the OP wants to match. It's always much easier to write regexps to match the strings we want than to not match similar strings we don't want, e.g. `.*` will match any string we want, including the ones in the OPs output, but it'll also match others.

Comment: @EdMorton, I aware, it's part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

either string style :

```
$4 ~ "^RRH[[]0_(9|1[01])_0[]][/]SFP[[]0[]]$"
```

or regex style

```
$4 ~ /^RRH[[]0_(9|10|11)_0[]]\/SFP[[]0[]]$/
```